# Problema con latex en Python funcion Sympy como lo resuelvo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex

Hace un par de semanas comencé a utilizar Python. El problema es que con la librería SymPy, usando el parámetro use_latex, el texto no sale en latex. Antes funcionaba y no se que pasó, sólo intenté imprimir en pantalla de la consola de Python. Ya reinicié el equipo, instalé de nuevo el programa y nada. Utilizo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Python 3.4.

Comment: ¿Ya instalaste LaTeX?

Comment: Hola Santiago, justo no se ve el comando `init_session` :/ ¿Puedes sacar otra captura un poco más arriba?

Comment: Mejor aún, pega tu código en vez de mostrar imágenes, así es más entendible

Comment: Pueden pasar varias cosas. Para renderizar latex, Jupyter usa MathJax. Parece que en sympy estás usando la opción de verlo como latex usando `sympy.init_printing()`. Desde jupyter 4.0 MathJax está dentro de tu carpeta *static* y no tiene que usar una conexión para descargarse una copia de MathJax.js. ¿Estás usando Jupyter >= v4.0?, si no es así, ¿tienes conexión a internet? Por favor, contesta a los comentarios para ir descartando cosas.